# Evaluate a sum involving the Mobius function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $m,n$ be natural integers and evaluate de sum

$$s=\sum_{r|m}\mu(r)(-1)^{(\frac{m}{r},n)}$$

**My Aproach**

I´m was using Mathematica and verify that $s$ must be $0$ again and again for diferent values of $m$ and $n$

Comment: If $m>1$ is odd, the value is zero. Also if $m>1$ and $n$ is odd.

Comment: If $n$ is even and $m$ is divisible by four, then the sum is zero as well.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(j,n) = (-1)^{(j,n)}$ and $s(m,n) = \sum_{r | m} \mu(r) g(m/r,n)$.
By the Möbius inversion formula, $g(j,n) = \sum_{r|j} s(r,n)$.
Then it turns out

$$ \eqalign{ s(1,n) &= -1 \cr
             s(2,n) &= 2 \ \text{if $n$ is even}\cr
             s(m,n) &= 0 \ \text{otherwise}\cr}
    $$

Comment: Isn't an $n$ missing as the second argument of $g$?

Comment: Thank you.... but why $s(m,n)=0$ otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if $m$ and $n$ are coprime, then for any divisor $r$ or $m$, $\dfrac{m}{r}$ and $n$ are also coprime. Therefore, for $m$ and $n$ such that $\gcd \left( m, n \right) = 1$, we get

$$s = - \sum\limits_{r | m} \mu \left( r \right) = \begin{cases} -1, & m = 1 \\ 0 & m > 1 \end{cases}$$

The case where $\gcd \left( m, n \right) > 1$ is a bit lengthy to write. However, I would like to hint that if you take prime factorization of $m$ and $n$, then you would have some prime factors common (powers as well). Also, notice that you only have to do the computation for square-free divisors of $m$. The rest will be zero due to definition of $\mu$.

Therefore, if $m = p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2} \cdots p_r^{k_r}$, where $k_i \geq 1$, then there would be $2^r$ computations involved.